# Airflow BashOperator return exit code 0 even when task failed and return exit code 1

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, amazon-eks, airflow

I am trying to run a spark job from airflow's bash operator with Kubernetes, I have configured callback_failure to some function, however even though spark job failed with exit code 1, my task is always marked as a success and function is not called( callbcak failure ). Following are snippets of airflow log:

```
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - 20/01/03 13:22:46 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Container final statuses:
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - 
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - 
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO -    Container name: spark-kubernetes-driver
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO -    Container image: XXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/spark-py:XX_XX
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO -    Container state: Terminated
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,730] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO -    Exit code: 1
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,731] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - 20/01/03 13:22:46 INFO Client: Application run_report_generator finished.
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,736] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - 20/01/03 13:22:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,737] {{bash_operator.py:128}} INFO - 20/01/03 13:22:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-adb99a7e-ce6c-49f6-8307-a17c28448043
[2020-01-03 13:22:46,761] {{bash_operator.py:132}} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2020-01-03 13:22:49,994] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [ [34m2020-01-03 13:22:49,994 [0m] {{ [34mlocal_task_job.py: [0m105}} INFO [0m - Task exited with return code 0
```

Comment: It looks like your bash script returns 0 when the container fails (See https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L136 for how the BashOperator handles exit codes). It succeeded in submitting the job, but my guess is that the Bash script does not check the results of the job. Can you post your script code + the BashOperator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `set -e` to ensure the `BashOperator` to stop execution and return error for any non-zero code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the last exit code is not 0 .

From your input you have this:

[2020-01-03 13:22:46,761] {{bash_operator.py:132}} INFO - Command exited with return code 0

and then the bash operator treats the whole operator job as success.

The solution is to make this exit code explicitly equal to 1.

For example in python you can have:

```
 import sys

 if condition_for_exiting:

    sys.exit(1)
```